# iterator delete in scala

Tags: java, scala

How can I convert this to scala since iterator has no remove method?
iter is defined like this:

```
Iterator<Integer> iter = cache.keySet().iterator();
```

where cache is a hashmap

```
while (iter.hasNext()) {
        int num = iter.next();
        if (!part.contains(num)){
            iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `iter` defined?

Comment: What do you need the iterator for, why not filter the `cache` directly with `cache.filter{ case (k, _) => part.contains(k) }`?

Comment: yes nice thought I guess this will work thanks

Comment: this will remove the tuples that do not contain num right?

Comment: @SuzyTros This will remove all tuples where the keys are not contained in `part`. This is what your iterator-loop does, if I'm not missing anything. See compilable example below.

Comment: @SuzyTros Updated my answer. If you are filtering the `cache` repeatedly, you should stick to `filter`, because `filterKeys` behaves quite differently (Thanks @SimY4 for pointing it out).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your actual goal is to filter some keys from the cache, you can do this directly, without loops and iterators:

```
val cache = Map("a" -> 3, "b" -> 5, "c" -> 7)
val part = Set("x", "y", "b")
val filteredCache = cache.filter{ case (k, _) => part.contains(k) }
// prints `Map(b -> 5)`, because "a" and "c" not in `part`
println(filteredCache)
```

**EDIT**

As @SymY4 has absolutely rightly noted, `filter` and `filterKeys` behave quite differently: `filter` returns a new Map (immutable version), or filters the elements in-place (mutable version). However, `filterKeys` only constructs a filtered view of the original collection. Therefore, calling `filterKeys` repeatedly is not advisable, because it would stack more and more views on top of each other.

However, the solution with `filter` should still be valid.

Comment: Doing a lot of filters on a map will eventually make resulting map too slow. I would say it's better to remove keys completely by doing: `val updatedCache 
= cache -- Set("x", "y", "b")`

Comment: @SimY4 Indeed, you are right about the `filterKeys`, it does not create a new collection, but instead returns a view of the old one. That's a nasty little pitfall... Thank you very much for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Doing a lot of filters on a map will eventually make resulting map too slow. Because you'll need to apply all the filters you've added before you reach the actual cache store. I suggest to remove elements from a map by using `--` syntax

```
scala> Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3)

scala> res0 -- Set("x", "y", "b")
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, c -> 3)
```

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion? The documentation says quite clearly that `filter` *"returns a **new traversable collection** consisting of all elements of this traversable collection that satisfy the given predicate p. The order of the elements is preserved."* (emphasis mine)

Comment: @AndreyTyukin have you looked into implementation? You will see that `filters` are wrappers around original collection. It helps to save a little in memory since you don't have to copy over the whole map, but eventually your map will become very slow. Try for yourself.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I was wrong, sorry. `filter` is working as you said. But `filterKeys` is wrapping everything in a Filter wrapper, so `filterKeys` will eventually be slow, not `filter`

Comment: At least the claim about `filter` is not reproducible in 2.12.4. If I define 
`val m = ((0 to 100) zip (400 to 5000)).toMap; val n = m.filter{ case (k, _) => k % 2 == 0 }`
and then show `m.getClass` and `n.getClass`, I get `scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap`
in both cases. If your scala does something else, you should either upgrade to a newer version or
submit a bug report. I'm looking at `filterKeys`, I don't use it often, maybe I indeed missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
val it = Iterator.continually(hashMap.headOption).takeWhile(_.isDefined).flatten
for ((key, value) <- it) {
    hashMap.remove(key)
    ... //do something here with value
}
```

where `hashMap` is a mutable HashMap instance.